# AngularJS ui-view displays nothing when running grunt serve:dist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I've been trying to make this code that I inherited work for a couple of days now but I still got no luck. Admittedly I am still a beginner in Angular but I think I already did what I could.

I'm using Yeoman's angular generator and grunt. `grunt serve` works fine but `grunt serve:dist` doesn't. At first it has something to do with some of the partial templates not getting included into `$templateCache` but I already fixed it. The templates are now included in the final script.js and the network tab of chrome dev tools no longer reports 404s. Debugging ui-router in the dist version of the application gives me `Unknown provider: aProvider <- a` which is apparently not very helpful. This is turning into a guessing game really. Below are code snippets. I hope somebody can help me out. Any advice would be good.

index.html

```
    <div id='main-container' ng-controller="AccountCtrl">
    <div id='logged-in-container' ng-if="isLoggedIn"><!-- container-fluid -->
        <div id='left-sidebar' class="col-lg-2 bg-dark-blue">
            <div id='left-sidebar-navigation' ng-controller="SidebarNavigationCtrl">
                <left-Sidebar-User-Profile></left-Sidebar-User-Profile>
                <left-Sidebar-Navigation></left-Sidebar-Navigation>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='main-container-body' class="col-lg-10"  ui-view >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='logged-off-container' ng-if="!isLoggedIn">
        <div class="col-lg-12"  ui-view >
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Please note the directives `left-Sidebar-User-Profile` and `left-Sidebar-Navigation` works. Only the `ui-view` doesn't.

app.js

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url:'/',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'AccountCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main',
    resolve: resolveLoggedIn
  });
```

I already tried changing the code above to the format like `views: { 'login': { url: ... } }` which I believe is the correct thing but I got the same behavior so I reverted my changes.

Gruntfile.js is [here](https://app.box.com/s/xp12zko6rjo6t9lgd19t68kedfwzthmd) as it's pretty long.

Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occuring because your angular code is not mininfication ready. For a better insight to the same, see [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-minutes-to-min-safe-angular-code-with-grunt/).

You should consider using something such as [grunt-ng-annotate](https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate)

Comment: Thanks. I have ng-annotate in place and currently following a different lead. But I would consider this if the app still doesn't work.

Comment: No luck on the annotations. In the end, my colleague was forced to do a hard reset and work from there. (Yeah, that sucks.) Things are okay now. I have little awareness of what happened though as of now. Sorry for that.